# After posting content of my blog ni, they are shown in html format rather than pure text

Tags: python, django, tinymce

I am using tinymce for my web blog that allows me to post my blogs, but as I post they are shown in rawHTML format like below:
[image]

this is my template

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block styler %}

{% endblock styler%}
{% block content %}

<div class="content-section">
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset>
            <legend class="border-bottom pb-3 mb-3">Post blog</legend>
            {{ form|crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

and my forms.py

```
class PostCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField()

    content = forms.CharField(
        widget=TinyMCEWidget(
            attrs={'required': False, 'cols': 30, 'rows': 10}
        )
    )

    thumbnail = forms.ImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'content', 'thumbnail']
```

and associated views.py

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostCreateForm
```

help me how to solve this problem, I searched a bit and find out this could be due to `@Html.Raw(@Model.LongDescription)` but I don't know either where do I have to add that? and please check if you can do any improvement for my code.
thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you just need to add safe tag: `{{ content|safe }}`

Or you can wrap html in autoescape tag:

```
{% autoescape off %}
  {{ content }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: Thank you man! that helped alot!
One more help: if you check www.simpleisbetterthancomplex.com website, you will see a reply and comment section! I see same reply and comment section in many django powered websites. can you please help me what is the name for that and how do I add that?

Comment: @Noor thats another big theme. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44837733/how-to-make-add-replies-to-comments-in-django